# What is the definition of this symbol $ \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} f(s) \, ds, \quad \sigma>0.$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

What is the definition of this symbol
$$ \int_{\sigma-i\infty}^{\sigma+i\infty} f(s) \, ds, \quad  \sigma>0.$$
Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "significance"?

Comment: my problem is with the extremities of the integral

Comment: This is the integral $$ i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(\sigma+it) \, dt=i\int_{\mathbb R} f(\sigma+it) \, dt$$

Comment: When you say "what's the significance," do you mean "what is the definition of this symbol"?

Comment: @Did Welcome back! Very good to see you around again.

Comment: @user Thanks. $ $

Comment: @ user and Did, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to integrate to get the Inverse Laplace Transform?

This integral is defined as a path integral over a vertical line on the C plane, usually it's done by finding the contour integral of the line plus part of a infinitely large circle centered at 0.